# The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I use Android API 19 and i want to pinpoint a location on my app, i can get location or see if GPS and Google play service is enable or not, no problem at those but when i want to show a map my problem begin.

I found an tutorial that say use **getFragmentManager** can do this but Eclipse gave me this error:

```
The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Mhelper
```

My class is :

```
package com.example.hach;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

//import com.example.hach.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v4.app.* ;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class Mhelper {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    public void pinpointlocation(Context context){

         map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview))
                    .getMap();
                Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                    .title("Hamburg"));
                Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(KIEL)
                    .title("Kiel")
                    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

                // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

                // Zoom in, animating the camera.
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
......
```

Then i search a little while and found a lot of offered solutions but non of them works for me and confused me more.

One solution told to pass Contex to the function , but other solution told it is because we should build class extends from Fragment and then use this function , other said to put these imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.* ;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

but same error, one of them suggest to use

```
((Activity)context).getFragmentManager()
```

but i get same error.

Even i use **getSupportFragmentManager()** but same error.

What should i do ? should i create a new class which extends from fragment ? is there any other simple way?

PS: 
I gave all sort of permissions in manifest xml and i put mapview on my layout xml and they gave me no error and i gave google api key for map,even it has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: Use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of that.

Comment: I used that , same error.

Comment: You are using support library for fragments. So instead of getFragmentManager() use getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview))
                    .getMap();
```

Comment: It gave me **The method getActivity() is undefined for the type Mhelper**

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity().

Answer (score -1):

Method getFragmentManager() of which class? Your Mhelper class not extend any another class and you not define ypur own getFragmentManager() method. So, how can it work?

Comment: And your solution is ?

Comment: To use getSupportFragmentManager() method you need extend your class from FragmentActivity or pass FragmentActivity instance in your class and use ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager() statement